# Read mms stream for open cv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, mms

Is there a way to read an mms stream, with open cv, for direct analyze?

I'm trying to do a small project with c++. and I don't know how to plug the mms to the opencv.

I guess ill need to add a library to the visual studio.

There is only video on the mms stream im reading:

```
mms://s3ewm.castup.net/991450009-52.wmv?ct=IL&rg=BZ&aid=145&tkn=20120201230602&ts=0&cu=FC1B06E9-7ABE-4B1C-9B2A-7A5C6019E99F
```

**Update:**

I found this link: [Microsoft msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390658%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=87031) someone did get the mms with vlc package.

```
struct ctx
{
   IplImage* image;
   HANDLE mutex;
   uchar*    pixels;
};

void *lock(void *data, void**p_pixels)
{
    struct ctx *ctx = (struct ctx*)data;
    WaitForSingleObject(ctx->mutex, INFINITE);
     *p_pixels = ctx->pixels;   
    return NULL;

}
void display(void *data, void *id){
   (void) data;
   assert(id == NULL);
}
void unlock(void *data, void *id, void *const *p_pixels){
   struct ctx *ctx = (struct ctx*)data;
   /* VLC just rendered the video, but we can also render stuff */
   uchar *pixels = (uchar*)*p_pixels;
   cvShowImage("image", ctx->image);
   ReleaseMutex(ctx->mutex);
   assert(id == NULL); /* picture identifier, not needed here */
}

int main()
{
   cvNamedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   libvlc_media_t* media = NULL;
   libvlc_media_player_t* mediaPlayer = NULL;
   char const* vlc_argv[] = {"--plugin-path", "C:\\Users\\Oscar\\Documents\\libvlc\\vlc-1.1.4"};
   libvlc_instance_t* instance = libvlc_new(2,vlc_argv);
   mediaPlayer = libvlc_media_player_new(instance);
   media = libvlc_media_new_path(instance, "mms://81.89.49.210/musicbox");

   struct ctx* context = ( struct ctx* )malloc( sizeof( *context ) );
   context->mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE,NULL);
   context->image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
        context->pixels = (unsigned char *)context->image->imageData;

   libvlc_media_player_set_media( mediaPlayer, media);
   libvlc_video_set_callbacks(mediaPlayer, lock, unlock, display, context);
        libvlc_video_set_format(mediaPlayer, "RV32", VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT, VIDEO_WIDTH*4);
   libvlc_media_player_play(mediaPlayer);


   while(1)
   {
   }
   return 0;
}
```